# VSCode - enlarge pop-up object inspector

Tags: visual-studio-code

Working in python in VSCode. Making heavy use of the object inspector (if that is what it is called - see image below) -- *the window that appears with object/variable contents when hover mouse over variable name in code.*

It is quite a small window and I *often* find myself wishing it was larger, or that it could be dragged/resized.

Is there a user-setting or other method to change the default size? Make it much larger?

[image: VSCode var/obj inspector popup]

Comment: I've been looking for this so long, have yet to find any way to do it though :( Standard Visual Studio here though

Comment: I opened this [as an issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63519)

Comment: Above github issued closed as duplicate. Issue was already opened as [Allow hover to be resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345519/vscode-enlarge-pop-up-object-inspector?noredirect=1#comment93732078_53345519). All future googlers are requested to visit the link and thumbs-up the issue description (click the smiley at top right and choose thumbs-up) to provide feedback to the authors.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually very simple. If you want to inspect variable (object, class, ...) 'foo', just type 'foo' into your debug console's command line and press enter. You now got the same interactive output from the fly-out in the more persistent and resizeable debug console window.